# Grade Unknown host 'services.gradle.org' error after entering proxy setting in Springboot

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, gradle-properties

I am following the springboot starter here https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/ and using the starter code.

I am getting a `ERROR: Unknown host 'services.gradle.org'. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle.` when I try to run gradle.

I have entered proxy information in user/.gradle/gradle.properties as documented here. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:accessing_the_web_via_a_proxy

I have also tried adding

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
System.setProperty('http.proxyHost', 'proxy.companyproxy.com:8080')
```

to my build.gradle file.
I am using mac and terminal and intelliJ proxy are also configured. Why is the proxy not coming through for gradle?
My build.gradle file: same as given in sample starter

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.3.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: So just to be clear on your situation...you must go through a proxy to reach the internet, and the address of that proxy is ` 'proxy.aexp.com:8080'`.  Is that correct?  If so, do you need credentials to connect to the proxy?

Comment: That error message says to to me that the target server can't resolve external domain names...that it's failing to turn `services.gradle.org` into an IP address.  Is this expected?  Even if you have to go through a proxy, I would think that DNS would work normally for you, although I've never had to work behind a proxy.  If you think DNS should be working without a proxy, you should try looking up that host at the host's console and maybe on other machines on the same network.  You can just use `ping`.

Comment: yes, I do need to go through a proxy. The credentials are entered in the user/.gradle/gradle.properties  I followed the documentation here. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:accessing_the_web_via_a_proxy

Comment: yeah, I am not able to ping through it with mac terminal. ping: cannot resolve services.gradle.org: Unknown host  But also the terminal do not have a proxy setup and I assume having a separate gradle proxy setting meaning it does not take proxy information from the terminal.

Comment: so I did a quick search, https://www.efficientip.com/web-proxy-not-enough/  it seems that the proxy also handles the dns resolution as well